# Why is Japanese considered not to have plural?

Tags: internationalization, gettext, cjk, poedit

Why is Japanese declared as having `Plural-Forms: nplurals=1; plural=0;` - i.e. there is no difference between singular and plural?

While it is true that the word for the singular and plural forms of a noun (let's say 'pencil') is the same (both are 'enpitsu'), aren't the phrases 'this pencil' and 'these pencils' different? The singular is 'Kono enpitsu', and the plural is 'Korera no enpitsu'. (Right?)

So why shouldn't I be able to do (in PHP):

```
ngettext('This pencil','These pencils', $n);
```

Even if I modify the `.po` file manually to the following:

```
msgid "This pencil"
msgid_plural "These pencils"
msgstr[0] "この鉛筆"
msgstr[1] "これらの鉛筆"
```

when I open the file with Poedit, it doesn't recognize the plural!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> So why shouldn't I be able to do (in PHP)

Because that's not what gettext plural forms [are for](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html). They are for strings *that contain a number*, e.g. ("%d pencil", "%d pencils"). That's why the `ngettext` function has an integer argument — the value to be inserted into the string.

Comment: OK. Thanks. And is there _another_ way of doing that, other than `$str = ($n > 1 ? _('These pencils') : _('This pencil'));`?

Comment: Actually @Václav, in that link you provided it says: It is also possible to use this function when the strings don’t contain a cardinal number: `puts (ngettext ("Delete the selected file?","Delete the selected files?",n));` In this case the number n is only used to choose the plural form.

Comment: @RamblinWreck Nevertheless, it *is* the answer to your question, which was "Why is Japanese a `nplurals=1` language?". This is why, the system is designed for numbers. Nothing prevents you from using custom `Plural-Forms` expressions, but if you explicitly differentiate between 1 and >1, then `if` is arguably the correct way. - it's a universal semantic distinction, not a linguistic one.

Comment: But by using `if` I am falling into the error of believing that by all languages the difference between singular and plural forms is going to depend on being one, or more than one. That is what ngettext is supposed to help with: allowing each translator to decide based on his language! Are there any Japanese readers out there that will agree or disagree with what I'm saying? How are others dealing with this issue? I can't imagine I'm the first one that noticed this!

Comment: `ngettext` has an integer argument because it obviously needs to know `n` somehow, but contrary to what was implied, `ngettext` does not insert anything to the string. The API is therefore perfectly suitable for strings without numbers, and it is even a documented use case pointed out in the provided link. Is there any actual evidence that gettext plural forms were not meant for this, other than Václav strongly thinking they weren't?

Comment: With gettext, the translator has the option to use a `Plural-Forms` expression of their own for a `.po` file. As already mentioned, if you wish to have more plurals, you can, by adjusting the `Plural-Forms` field.

Comment: @LauriNurmi I specifically answered the question of why the default plural form for Japanese is what it is. This *is* why. This is the default *gettext* form, not something *I* made up or any software written by me forces upon users. If you don't think this very fact is strong evidence of what the original intent in gettext API design was, I don't know what would be. Whether gettext can be used in different ways (yes, as pointed out by others here) or whether the gettext design is sufficient for all pluralization needs (hell no, not by a long shot) are different questions...

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to change the plural header in the Japanese PO file if you really run into that issue.  But that will probably not happen.

Turkish and Hungarian seem to behave the same as Japanese in that respect and their respective language teams have decided to use `nplurals = 2; plural=(n != 1)` as the default `Plural-Forms`. But I cannot find any example where `msgstr[0]` and `msgstr[1]` really differ for these languages and that shows that the question you are asking is probably an academic one.

The gettext framework is not meant for translating literature.  In German - and maybe more languages - for instance, it is recommended to write out small numbers (zero to twelve) and use digits only for larger numbers.  But should German then be considered to have 14 plural forms for the purpose of `ngettext()`?

Keep in mind, too, that `ngettext()` can only translate simple expressions like "one file deleted"/"%d files deleted".  You cannot use it for expressions like "%d files and %d directories deleted".

Also, this piece of code would be incorrect:

```c
ngettext("One file deleted.  You can find it in the recycle bin.",
         "%d files deleted.  You can find them in the recycle bin.",
         number_of_files);
```

That would produce nonsense for `number_of_files == 0`, regardless of the language.  You could fix that by changing the `Plural-Forms` of all of your PO files, including English, making sure that `n == 0` always has a distinct plural form, and then put this into the PO file:

```
msgid "One file deleted.  You can find it in the recycle bin."
msgid_plural "%d files deleted.  You can find them in the recycle bin."
msgstr[0] "No file deleted."
msgstr[1] "One file deleted.  You can find it in the recycle bin."
msgstr[2] "%d files deleted.  You can find them in the recycle bin."
```

That would work. But should you do that? No. You should just work around the problem in the code, not in the PO file.  And if your translator for Japanese complains that they have to distinguish between "この鉛筆" and "これらの鉛筆", it is probably easier to find a workaround in your code instead of changing the PO header.

And while you are implementing the workaround, it is quite likely that you see that you also have to handle the case `n == 0` specially.  That's why the decision of the Japanese language team about their default `Plural-Forms` expression is probably appropriate for the vast majority of cases.